# Using both "static" and "concrete" generic types

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

So, I would like to pass both a "type" to work on, as well as a function that operates on a concrete value of that type.

I'm hoping there's a less verbose way to do this, but I'm not sure.

I've figured out that you can say `typeof MyClass` to indicate the "static" type, whereas just `MyClass` is the concrete type.

Here is an example of the function I would like to call:

```
function SomeFunction<TStatic, TConcrete, TKey>(
   type: TStatic,
   keyGetter: (value: TConcrete) => TKey
): (key: TKey) => TConcrete
   ...
```

Calling it looks like:

```
Module.SomeFunction<typeof SomeType, SomeType, string>(SomeType, value => value.SomeText);
```

Without the long type list, it can't infer that value is `SomeType`, but if I specify it explicitly, I can simplify it to this and still get the right types:

```
Module.SomeFunction(SomeType, (value: SomeType) => value.SomeText);
```

There is a version of the function that is meant to be simpler when I know that I have a `Text` property:

```
function SomeFunction2<TStatic, TConcrete extends { Text: string }>(
  type: TStatic
): (key: string) => TConcrete {
   return Module.SomeFunction<TStatic, TConcrete, string>(type, value => value.Text);
}
```

But using it, it can't infer the type of `TConcrete`, so I end up with this as the simplest version if I want the types to be correct:

```
Module.SomeFunction2<typeof SomeType, SomeType>(SomeType);
```

What I would really like to say is just this, which would probably work fine in C#:

```
Module.SomeFunction(SomeType, value => value.Text);
Module.SomeFunction2(SomeType);
```

Can I somehow get rid of this distinction between `TStatic` and `TConcrete` or do anything else that could let me simplify this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, `TStatic` and `TConcrete` are not independent. What you are passing when you pass the type name is actually the constructor for the class. We can specify the signature for the constructor instead of `TStatic` this will help the compiler infer the types better.

```
function SomeFunction<TConcrete, TKey>(
    type: new (...params: any[]) => TConcrete,
    keyGetter: (value: TConcrete) => TKey
): (key: TKey) => TConcrete {
    // ...
}


SomeFunction(SomeType, (value) => value.SomeText); // Works fine
```

**Note:** I tested on the latest typescript, I see the question is tagged with 1.8, it should work the same, but let me know in the comments if it works for you.